# Pointer to base class with template inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, smart-pointers

I have a templated interface, various derived templated classes, various function associated to the derived templated classes, and a std container supposedly containing pointers to instances of the templated interface :

```
class Collider<T> {}
class BoxCollider<T> : public Collider<T> {}
class CircleCollider<T> : public Collider<T> {}

bool intersects(BoxCollider<T> b1, BoxCollider<U> b2) { ... }
bool intersects(BoxCollider<T> b, CircleCollider<U> c) { ... }
bool intersects(CircleCollider<T> b, BoxCollider<U> c) { ... }
bool intersects(CircleCollider<T> c1, CircleCollider<U> c2) { ... }
```

And I want to do something like this :

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Collider<float>>> colliders;
    CircleCollider<float> player(...);
    ...
    for(auto it = colliders.begin(); it != colliders.end(); it++) {
        auto collider = *it;
        if(intersects(player, *collider) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't, I understand why (apparent type != real type...), I tried a lot of other ways to do what I need to (like dynamicaly casting pointers) but I still can't do what I need to... Please can someone tell me what's the best way to do that ?

Thanks a lot =)

Comment: You should rewrite `intersects` function as a `Collider` class virtual method and overload it in each of inherited classes, so object will know which function to call

Comment: This is the classical multiple dispatch problem. Google it, google "visitor pattern", google "acyclic visitor". It has nothing to do with templates BTW.

Comment: @Denis : i'm sure intersects shouldn't be a member method of Collider since its parameters are "symetric". At least it could be a static method but it wouldn't solve the problem =/

Comment: @n.m. : i'm gonna check that then, thanks :) And yep I was pretty sure it had nothing to do with templates but it made me debugging and trying other methods so hard that I doubt x)